# Can concentration and wisdom be developed exclusively from each other?

Tags: practice, samadhi, wisdom, panna

Can you develop Samadhi (concentration) and Pañña (wisdom) exclusively from one another (according to the suttas)?

I am under the impression that a meditator cannot develop one without developing the other.

Comment: my answer is here: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/33157/8157

Comment: Thank you very much 

Comment: But my question is not distinguishing Vippassana as opposed to Samatha but wisdom as opposed to samādhi instead.

Comment: Right Samadhi is lead by Right Wisdom (Panna). Wrong Samadhi is not lead by wisdom. Refer to MN 117: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html, which says: "Any singleness of mind equipped with these seven factors — right view, right resolve, right speech, right action, right livelihood, right effort, & right mindfulness — is called noble right concentration with its supports & requisite conditions."

Comment: But can't you, in the 5 faculties, develop wisdom exclusively.

Comment: Question reopened based on "But my question is not distinguishing Vippassana as opposed to Samatha but wisdom as opposed to samādhi instead".

Answer (score 1):

Yes according to the Suttas one can develop concentration separate or in tandem with wisdom.

[AN 4.170](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.170.than.html)

Answer (score -3):

You can't have wisdom apart from vipassana either.  Think of samadhi as the ingredients, vipassana as the blender, and prajna as the milkshake.

Comment: Terrible and incorrect metaphor.

Comment: Care to elaborate?  Samadhi creates the potentiality for insight ("When my concentrated mind was thus purified, bright, unblemished, rid of imperfection, malleable, wieldy, steady, and attained to imperturbability..."), vipassana is the act of directing that mind; it's the mechanism in this process ("I directed it to"), and prajna is the fruit of that direction ("knowledge of the destruction of the taints. I directly knew as it actually is: ‘This is suffering’..." (MN 4)